# how to make the treeview label in kivy visible background color

Tags: python, kivy, treeview

I am trying to make my treeview label visible, I mean when I do tree view and run and expand the tree, I can see the problem is that other UI element like text input is visible and I don't want that and I can't make the selection if it's above text input

```
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeViewLabel,TreeView, TreeViewNode
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
class Accounting(App):
    def build(self):
        tree=TreeView(hide_root=True)
        root=tree.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text='choose'))
        for a in range(100):
            tree.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=str(a),even_color=(0,0,0,0)),root)
        # if you try here to change the color visibility the numbers will appears but you can't select it
        textinput=TextInput(hint_text='textinput',foreground_color=(1,1,1,1),background_color=(0,0,0,0))
    
        layout=BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        layout.add_widget(tree)
        layout.add_widget(textinput)

        return layout

Accounting().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. It is not necessary to hide the text field, but it looks better to me

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeViewLabel
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = """
FloatLayout:
    TextInput:
        id: text_field
        size_hint_y: None
        pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.5}
        height: self.minimum_height
        
    ScrollView:
        TreeView:
            id: tv
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            hide_root: True
            on_node_expand: app.hide(True)
            on_node_collapse: app.hide(False)
"""


class Accounting(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        root = self.root.ids.tv.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text="Choose"))
        for a in range(100):
            self.root.ids.tv.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=str(a)), root)

    def hide(self, hide):
        if hide:
            self.root.ids.text_field.foreground_color = (1, 1, 1, 1)
            self.root.ids.text_field.background_color = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        else:
            self.root.ids.text_field.foreground_color = (0, 0, 0, 1)
            self.root.ids.text_field.background_color = (1, 1, 1, 1)


Accounting().run()
```